# Does specific type affect performance of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, performance, types, arraylist

I wonder if `ArrayList<SimpleObject>` and `ArrayList<ComplexObject>` has different performance effect if we are concerning on memory usage and navigating speed (foreach, getAt())? Why?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you clarify your question? At the moment it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: look at your question again..? its asking for nothing valid...

Comment: I think he means ArrayList and ArrayList<K>

Comment: Thanks sepp2k for editing the format. It lost <K>. It's correct now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear on what you are looking for, so I've made a few assumptions about what you are seeking.

If your concern is of the memory used by the list, then it will depend on the actual size of the objects being managed by the `ArrayList`. If `SimpleObject`s are lightweight compared to `ComplexObjects` then the memory consumed on the heap will be higher in the latter case. However, the actual memory consumed by the array lists will be more or less constant for arraylists of equal number of objects, as the lists only contain references to the actual objects on the heap.

On the topic of runtime performance, this depends on the method being invoked. Methods like `get(int index)` and `add(E element)` will always have the same runtime performance characteristics irrespective of the type being used. This is due to the nature of the method: their behavior does not depend on the type of the Object present in the list.

On the other hand, the performance of `indexOf(Object object)` will depend on how the `equals` method is implemented. For trivial cases, it would easy to infer that `indexOf` will run faster for `ArrayList<SimpleObject>` than for `ArrayList<ComplexObject>`, assuming that the `equals()` implementation of `SimpleObject` will run faster than that of `ComplexObject`.

If your concern is of memory consumption during execution of the `ArrayList` methods, then it is not bound to be different as most of the methods work off references of objects. There are exceptions like `toArray()` which would require less memory for `SimpleObject` than for `ComplexObject`.

Comment: Why is it "more memory for SimpleObject than for ComplexObject"in toArray()?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no performance difference. There are two very simple arguments to explain this:

- An `ArrayList` only ever handles references and references are always the same size, no matter how complex the thing is they point to.
- Generics are implemented using erasure, which essentially means that at runtime the information that one is an `ArrayList<SimpleObject>` and the other is an `ArrayList<ComplexObject>` is *not available*, they are just `ArrayList` objects to the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

it does make no difference, because what we store in ArrayList() is just an object reference and not the memory. so no issue what kind of class you put in to it.. so there is no performance hindrance for large class and no enhanced performance for smaller classes..